# VisualWebGui Experience

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, ria, rich-internet-application

Has anybody experiences with **VisualWebGui** (http://www.visualwebgui.com/)? Can it be recommended to build RIA-Applications instead of using **Silverlight**?

Comment: @Kottan- did you work with VisualWebGui in the end? do you have insights ?